# Highcharts. How to export with different labels containing no HTML?

Tags: highcharts, export

We use HTML content when we display our Highchart chart. But when we export, the resulting image contains the HTML markup. Is there a way we can supply labels without HTML to only export so the export will display similar to how it is rendered to the user in the browser?

Tried without any success, exporting.allowHTML: true
We currently use labels.formatter to supply the labels with HTML markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite your `formatter` function only for exporting by using `exporting.chartOptions`.

For example:

```
  exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      yAxis: {
        labels: {
          useHTML: false,
          formatter: function() {
            return this.value;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gwbx16yr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions

Comment: Perfect, we got this to work after also updating from v2.0.4 up to v11.0. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing with the Title of the chart? We have a short title in the UI but we want a longer one when we export

Comment: Hi @Ben Williams, Yes, you can do the same with a title. Live exmaple: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5dqeun8L/